# When will these functions be different?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, discrete-mathematics

I participated in a Codeforces challenge recently, and as part of a solution, I wrote the following helper:

```py
def fun1(n, target):
    q, r = divmod(n, target)
    
    if r == 0:
        return target, q-1
    else:
        return r, q
```

My code failed on one test case I couldn't see (and still can't, since the test cases get cut off), but I've found that a correct solution uses

```py
def fun2(n, target):
    q, r = divmod(n, target)
    
    if r == 0:
        return target, q-1
    else:
        return n // (q+1), q
```

When will these two functions not output the same thing?

Comment: n=89 target=12 produces different results, just to pick one example out of the air.

Comment: Did you try just plugging in some numbers? There's no reason to expect `r` and `n // (q+1)` to be equal. They're usually not.

Comment: For float numbers also, try `fun1(0.1, 1)`

Comment: Try: `for i in range(11, 20): print(i, fun1(i, 10), fun2(i, 10))` and you'll see they're different for 12 through 18.

Answer (score 1):

`r` contains the result of `n % target` which is equivalent to `n - (n // target) * target`.

This is different from `n // (q+1)` which is equivalent to `n // (n // target + 1)`

There is no reason to expect those to always give the same result.